# How to extract substrings using Right, Left, Mid, LEN and FIND

Tags: function, excel-formula, substring

I am trying to extract data from a string using different functions.

I have the input data in the first column, which can have two different formats.

Here is an example for both formats, with the expected output next to it:

| Data | First name | Last name | Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `**NM1*IL*1*EEKS*MILBORD****MI*123456789~**` | `EEKS` | `MILBORD` | `123456789` |  |
| `**DTP*472*D9*20240212~ **` |  |  |  | `20240212` |

Currently, I got as far as these results:

| Data | MIDFUNCTION | First name | Nmbr | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `**NM1*IL*1*EEKS*MILBORD****MI*123456789~**` | `EEKS*MILBORD****MI*123456789~` | `EEK` | `BORD****MI*123456789` |  |
| `**DTP*472*D9*20240212~ **` |  |  |  | `20240212~` |

For the `mid` function -- which I placed in the D column -- I used:

```
=MID(A15,FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15)+9,LEN(A15)-FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15))
```

For the first name I used: `=LEFT(D15,FIND("*",D15)-1)`

For the Nmbr I used: `=RIGHT(A15,FIND("****MI*",A15))`

For the date I could not exclude the tilde. I used: `=RIGHT(A16,FIND("*D9*",A16))`

What I want is to extract using the find and Len based on the data in the data field... The `mid` function seems to work but does not exclude what is not needed.

I am trying to extract First Name, Last Name, Number and on the next line, the date and exclude the tilde.

Comment: Can you clarify how the data is formatted, the way it is in the body doesn't make it clear what values populate the cells. Additionally, please show what the expected end result would be for this. We know First Name & Last Name, but it's also not clear where that is in the text.

Comment: this is the value in the data cell:**NM1*IL*1*EEKS*MILBORD****MI*123456789~**

Comment: The "squiggly line" is called a [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)

Comment: this is the value in the date cell:  **DTP*472*D9*20240212~ **                                                                  I am trying to extract from both using the left, right, mid, LEN and FIND functions, and I added the examples that I used and what was extracted, if that makes sense.

Comment: @MrsTaft clarify that point in your question as well as explaining what the expected end result would be. We won't recognize the info you want to extract the way you would unless it's explained. Does the length of the data cell change (probably if the names vary), but all things that need to be explained in the question for better help.

Comment: I tried to create a table but I am new here and it did not alow me to add an image. once I submitted it everything looked different.

Comment: for the most part all the values with the name and number start with **NM1*IL*1*, which is why I used the find to extract, and the same with date, the length will change if the name is different as you stated. I showed the mid function that I used to extract the data which is MID(A15,FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15)+9,LEN(A15)-FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15))

Comment: What is D15, what is A3? What do you consider the be the first name, the last name and the number?

Comment: that is the cells in excel, pulled from Cell A3 or D15 when I was trying to extract and I used different cells as I was practicing trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I know those are cell references, but it is not clear what values they have.

Comment: First: EEKS  Last: MILBORD   Number: 23456789~

Comment: Okay, and the prefix and suffix of the data is a constant length? What about the expected result from the second row "**DTP*472*D9*20240212~ **"?

Do the * remain constant as well?

Comment: @MarkS if I am understanding the questions correctly yes.

Comment: @MarkS. Yes I am trying to pull the info after D9*

Comment: @trincot the values for all will be the name, and number with the **NM1*IL*1* in the begining of each field

Comment: To extract the last name you can try `=RIGHT(LEFT(A2,FIND("****",A2)-1),LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND("****",A2)-1))-FIND("*",LEFT(A2,FIND("****",A2)-1),12))` substituting A2 for the cell with the data in it. For first name try `=RIGHT(LEFT(A2,FIND("*",A2,12)-1),LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND("*",A2,12)-1))-FIND("*",LEFT(A2,FIND("*",A2,12)-1),10))` changing A2 to the data cell. For the number you can use `=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,12),9)`, again changing A2 to your data cell. Date use: `=LEFT(RIGHT(A3,13),8)`

Comment: I would suggest not creating a monster formula. Create little formulas that only find the key positions (start of first name, end of first name, end of last name, start of number, end of number,...) Once you have all of those, it is a piece of cake to create the `MID` functions you need for each of the texts you need to extract.

Comment: @trincot I would usually use a mid function, but with uncertainty in length of the needed First name, last name, and multiple instances of the separator, figured this will suffice, but would like to see your formula.

Comment: @trincot Using a mid function that handles variable length of the first name ends up still looking pretty ugly: `=MID(A2,FIND("*",A2,11)+1,FIND("*",A2,12)-FIND("*",A2,11)-1)` unless you found a better way.

Comment: thanks @MarkS. for the most part this gets me most of what I was looking for. I will play with it , I appreciate both of your help

Comment: had used the mid but I did not pull out what I needed, just excluded some.  MID(A15,FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15)+9,LEN(A15)-FIND("NM1*IL*1*",A15))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to really do this step by step, using intermediate cells for intermediate results. First get all key positions in the data, and only when you have all of them, design your `mid` extractions based on those positions.

I would use these formulas. I'm assuming the data is in column A, and starting at A2. Then I'd allocate the columns as follows:

| # | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data | Start First | End First | End Last | Start Num | End Num | Start Date | First Name | Last Name | Number | Date |
| 2 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Use these formulas:

- In B2: `=FIND("*1*",A2)+3`
- In C2: `=FIND("*",A2,B2)+1`
- In D2: `=FIND("*",A2,C2)`
- In E2: `=FIND("*MI*",A2,D2)+4`
- In F2: `=FIND("~",A2,E2)`
- In G2: `=FIND("*D9*",A2)+4`
- In H2: `=IFERROR(MID(A2,B2,C2-B2-1),"")`
- In I2: `=IFERROR(MID(A2,C2,D2-C2),"")`
- In J2: `=IFERROR(MID(A2,E2,F2-E2),"")`
- In K2: `=IFERROR(DATE(MID(A2,G2,4),MID(A2,G2+4,2),MID(A2,G2+6,2)),"")`

This is the result I got with that:

[image]

To have so many intermediate cells may look like overkill, but it makes it easier to see where things go wrong if they do. Once all is fine, you can just hide columns B-G.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfection, also helps me understand the functions a lil better. appreciate you

Comment: Answer has been accepted! thanks again